# asp.net c# compiler error CS1061

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, compiler-errors, runtime-error

i worked on my college project social net site.....there some critical problem hear....
-->when i drag an drop button or image button there page run easily but after double click on it aspx.cs page open there no code wright still page show CS1061-error .

after click on button generate click event....

```
namespace newsns
{
    public partial class WebForm6 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

-->there no problem in any class any namespace...or any code ....so why browser show this msg

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.forgotpassword_aspx' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Button1_Click1' and no extension method
>   'Button1_Click1' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ASP.forgotpassword_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 331:             Line 332:
>    Line 333:               
>   Text="Button" /> Line 335:
>
> Source File: c:\Users\DHAVAL\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\NEWSNS\newsns\forgotpassword.aspx    Line: 333

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Show Complete Compilation Source:

-->there my some page can not show this error but other page show it....why...?????
please answer my que....i'm new in c# asp.net...and i lost my more time to find solution...

i try all ways to solve problem....but it still embarrass me.

Comment: It's possible that the code behind file for the `ASPX` isn't setup properly. Check the `CodeBehind` attribute on the `<%@ Page` directive at the top of the `ASPX` page. Does that file name match where the code is in your example?

Comment: all code is set properly......file name ,classname ,namespaces all match properly...when i create project some page work great but now add new page also same error.i check most of all site related this topic no single one can proper answer it.

Comment: can you please paste the code for forgotpassword.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i think if you rebuild your application solved this problem

if you use any asp control you must redeploy your app or web app to locate related dll file into bin folder .

good luck

Answer (score 0):

With the same error I have to suffered and solved it. The reason behind this is as follows:
If you have forgotten the any {} or if you are using any logical operator then please check it properly by changing it to > or <. You will solve this very soon.